# Extending the capacity of the Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, audio, ssd

I was wondering if it is possible to substitute an internal laptop Hard Drive, with a 256 GB capacity, for another Hard Drive of 500 GB.
I was also wondering if my laptop has an SSD card. It is a Toshiba SATELLITE L745-S4210. I didn´t know what an SSD card is, and i still don´t know it very well. But someone suggested that I could replace an SSD card to increase the audio quality of my audio works.
Couldn't I replace the Hard Drive in order to increase the audio quality aswell? Sorry if my questions are a bit unclear...

Comment: No, replacing your hard drive will not increase your audio quality.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Although it is quite unlikely, if the audio wiring is of low quality or unshielded then there exists the possibility of the HDD causing signal interference either via moving parts and vibration, or electrical interference. If the audio has static then it is not outside the realm of possibilities to fix it by replacing the HDD with an SSD.

Comment: that model is a low end item from 4 years ago, the probability of it having an SSD is negligible. Although, that model is supposedly equipped with a 640GB hdd, so if you have 256GB, it could have been swapped with an SSD, as that is a common SSD size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alot of stuff going on here.. First things first... what are you doing with your pc? audio processing or movie production or just simply surfing the internet and listening to music?

Improving audio does not come from changing hard drive.. changing hard drives does not change what speakers are pyshically in the computer.. to do this you should buy a decent set of desktop speakers and call it a day if you just want to improve quality.. there's more that goes into that like source of the music file and type but if your streaming then you dont have to worry about that...

Now, to clarify this SSD shenanigans... SSD means solid state hard-drive and HDD is a hard disk hard drive..  if you only have a max capacity on your hard-drive of 256 you may already have a SSD installed but I feel like you would know it if you did ... but to check you hit windows button and search for "optimize drives: and next to C:\ it will tell you what the "media type" is..

Unless you are saying you only have 256 gbs left of a stock HDD.. which.. is plenty .. you can run disk clean up and defrag and clean up the computer but you are good with over 200gbs of space.

For a 500gbs SSD you are looking to spend a couple hundred $dollars$ (USD) for something you may not need.  Check out external harddrives you can get a 1 Tera byte drive for under 100$ USD these days..

*FINAL THOUGHTS*

1) Run a disk clean up and defrag and possible buying a external hard drive for storage

2) Put money into desktop speakers if you want to improve audio quality - not much can be done besides replace and the internal speakers.. and thats not worth the headache...

3) if you are doing audio/video production a SSD would help with overall performance of the software youre running not sound quality though.. it would be less choppy but not cleaner ... stick to what you got if you arent though

GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 1):

Usually to increase the size of your HDD make your computer and you happier.
You can substitute the internal HDD.

SSD usually is for [Solid State Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive).

About the connection with *"Audio quality of your work"* feel you free to ask again to the original *prompter* because it's rather unclear. The only possible reason that I can imagine is that you have to save in a low quality format the files you are processing due to lack of spaces on the HDD.

You can download the specifications of your laptop from the site of the prodicer [Toshiba](http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=3025145) click on the tab *Manuals & Specs*.

You can read about that model, for example, on a [specialized magazine](http://www.pcworld.com/product/1301052/toshiba-satellite-l745-s4210-notebook.html) too.